# Problems in TTTableview class using Three20 in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20, ttthumbsviewcontroller

Now I am using [Three20](http://three20.info) in my apps. I have a problem, when I run the application with `MainWindow.xib`, the `TTTableview` class isn't called. But without `MainWindow.xib` it would call the `TTTableview` class. I don't know why it's happening. Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add more code in order for us to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

In your AppDelegate code

delete the mainWindow.xib

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary 

    *)launchOptions {  

        if (![navigator restoreViewControllers]) {
                [navigator openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:kAppRootURLPath]];
            }

    }
```

## In main.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"YOURAppDelegate");
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```